# Why $2n−1$ comparisons are sometimes necessary to correctly merge two sorted sequences

Tags: data-structures

How we can prove that $2n−1$ comparisons are sometimes necessary to correctly merge two sorted sequences of $n$ elements each into one sorted sequence? I tried to prove it with binary decision tree, but it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Let the sequences be $A_{1..n}$ and $B_{1..n}$, merging takes $2n - 1$ comparisons if $A_1 < B_1 < A_2 < B_2 < A_3 < B_3 < \cdots < A_n < B_n$.

It compares $A_1$ with $B_1$, $A_2$ with $B_1$, $A_2$ with $B_2$, $A_3$ with $B_2$, $A_3$ with $B_3$, to $A_n$ with $B_n$.

It is identical to $A_1$ with $B_1$, $B_1$ with $A_2$, $A_2$ with $B_2$, $B_2$ with $A_3$, $A_3$ with $B_3$, to $A_n$ with $B_n$.

It requires each $A_i$ and $B_j$ comparison above be made to distinguish $A_i < B_j$ and $A_i > B_j$.

It resembles the original condition, so there are $2n$ elements linked by $2n - 1$ inequalities.

Comment: This doesn't prove that $2n - 1$ comparisons are *necessary*, just that this particular method of merging uses that many.

Comment: No, because for it to be necessary you must prove there doesn't exist some other algorithm that could do better.

Comment: It is not unknown, see the answer of the linked duplicate question, which refers to Theorem M in Chapter 5.3.2 of Volume 3 of the TAOCP by Knuth.

Comment: It is definitely similar, but you need to argue that this holds regardless of algorithm. You have the right idea but need to argue from the opposite direction: that you *need* to compare $A_1$ with $B_1$, for example.

Comment: Take any B_k. You must compare it to A_k and A_k+1, otherwise an array with A_k > B_k or A_k+1 < B_k would not be sorted correctly. That’s true for all k except k=n-1 where A_k+1 does not exist, so 2n-1 comparisons are needed. Other arrays may need fewer comparisons.

Comment: @orlp I added the fourth line, the proof is now clearly *sufficient*. But is the fourth line *necessary*? Isn't this method of merging guaranteed to produce the least number of comparison? We could use bogo sort to merge, but it is not necessary to perform that many comparisons.